# Shiny: reactive header based on file input

Tags: r, shiny

I want to have the header of my Shiny program be reactive to the file input by updating itself with the uploaded file name. Here's what I have:

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("File"),
    sidebarPanel( 
       fileInput("file1", "Upload a file:", 
                  accept = c('.csv','text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain'),
                  multiple = F) ) ))
```

server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    in_data <- reactive({
       inFile <- input$file1
       if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)   
       read.csv(inFile$datapath, as.is=T)
    }) })
```

Basically, I want to update the headerPanel so it says "File [name]" after the user uploads a file. I'm getting stuck accessing ui.R in server.R . I tried calling in_data() in server.R and it couldn't find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use `uiOutput` where you have `headerPanel`, e.g.,

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
    uiOutput("header_panel"),
    sidebarPanel( 
        fileInput("file1", "Upload a file:", 
                  accept = c('.csv','text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain'),
                  multiple = F
        ) 
    ),
    mainPanel()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    in_data <- reactive({
       inFile <- input$file1
       if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)   
       read.csv(inFile$datapath, as.is=T)
    }) 

    output$header_panel <- renderUI({
       inFile <- input$file1
       if (is.null(inFile)) headerPanel('File')
       else headerPanel(paste('File', inFile$name))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```